# how i can make my web site refresh or reload by itself in (HTML) code?

Tags: php, html

i need make my web sity refresh itself every 5 min in HTML code

i'm using PHP also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

Answer (score 7):

For a straight HTML solution you could use *meta-refresh*:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

Here's a quick tutorial - http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/index_tagsupp_4.html

However, it's worth noting this can be poor UX as visitors of your site will suddenly have the page refresh. I would encourage you to determine what *sections* of your page *need* refreshing and look into AJAX or another approach for updating the content in a less forceful way.

Comment: very good answer. The OP should accept this answer and close this topic.